# Xamarin iOS Storyboard not rendering

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard, xamarin

I got this error "There was a problem rendering this document" when i tried to load my storyboard in my xamarin iOS application. I created another xamarin iOS project and still got the same error.

Comment: Did you recently update Xamarin.iOS? Did you try rebuilding the project and re-opening the file?

Comment: I updated Xamarin.iOS last week, with no issues, I tried rebuilding, re-creating the project. restarted my machine, still no result.

Comment: If you open the OS X `Console.app` app, you should be able to see an error message, can you post it?

Comment: I am using visual studio. on a windows PC.

Comment: Try looking up the error in the VS log: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-with-the-activity-log.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can not do much there right now.

There are two options one should do:
1. Use Xcode storyboard if you can.
2. If the first one is not an option, create and use multiple storyboards in your project, since after your storyboard gets big enough xamarin has a lot of problems rendering and working with it. You have a lot of documentation on how to use multiple storyboards in your project.